# Creating an "Injector" class in Swift that configures objects it receives

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dependency-injection

I want to create a dependency injection pattern, where objects are sending themselves to be configured by an external Injector class. The external Injector will look for objects that conform to a certain protocol, and configure attributes for the received object, based on that.

I had this pattern implemented in Objective C: the init method would call the Injector with parameter "self", and then the Injector would call setters for the missing dependencies.

In Swift however, a method needs to receive "inout" parameters to be able to change their properties, and you cannot send self as an inout parameter (for good reason, as I understand).

Still, how can I do this in SWIFT?

Comment: Could you post your ObjC code? So I could give you the matching Swift Code :-)

Comment: As long as `self` is a reference type (a class) you don't need it to be an `inout` parameter.  If you're basing this on an Objective-C implementation, wouldn't it have used classes a well (unless you've decide to go for structs in Swift instead)?